# How can I pass the return value from mongo query to express template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to create a helper function to use in the template.

```
var User = require("../models/user");
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

function retrieveUser(id, callback) {
    User.find(ObjectId(id), {image: 1, _id: 0}, function(err, users) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
      } else {
        callback(null, users[0]);
      }
    }).lean();
  };
function getUserImage(id){
    user_image = null;
    retrieveUser(id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(user.image);
        user_image = user.image
        // do something with user
    });
  return user_image;
}

module.exports.getUserImage = getUserImage;
```

I see the correct value in the console.log , **But** when I call this

`<%=getUserImage("5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e")%>`

`home.ejs` for example is give me `undefined`.

How should I create the this helper in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because `retrieveUser` is an asynchronous function so the `return user_image` statement does not wait for `retrieveUser` to complete. You can use synchronous version of this function (if exists) or you should first call and collect `user_image` before calling the render function and pass it to the render function in your route. In my opinion, keeping in mind the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, the 2nd approach is write way to go.

You can write your middleware to look something like this -

```js
    (req, res, next) => {
     retrieveUser(<ID>, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.render('view_name', { image: user.image });
    });
}
```

This is only a pseudo code you can use this concept in your code however you like. Just remember that render must be called in the callback function.

Comment: could help give sample of answer with your code solution

Comment: it is like more complicated for me , and I don't know what todo, very beginner for me

Comment: If it looks more complicated then you can use async await to simplify it. However in that case you will have to modify the retrieveUser function to return a promise and not use callback.